# Is it bad to publish only in specialized math journals?

Tags: journals, mathematics

I work in the field of algebra (more specifically the representation theory of groups).  I published most of my papers in journals of algebra and another algebra journal of similar quality as journal of algebra and think about having some papers now in slightly better journals. (It would be good if the editorial board has some names close to my field of research, but this is optional.)
Here are some examples that come to my mind: Mathematische Zeitschrift, the Journals of the London mathematical society, IMRN.

- Is it considered to be much better to have a publication in such a general journal than in a specialized journal like Journal of Algebra? I made the experience that sending my papers to Journal of Algebra, one gets a much quicker publication and the editors are closer to my field. So from my side I would just send all my papers to Journal of Algebra or another specialised journal, but I assume that this will look weird in my CV.  Does it harm me if I do this even when some of my papers could go into a slightly better journal like Mathematische Zeitschrift? I feel uncomfortable sending my papers to editors that are far away from my field of research.

Some secondary questions:

- How bad is it to have a very good paper (that might be suitable for the best general journals) published in a journal like Journal of Algebra?
- Can one give an approximate how much worth a paper in Advances of Math (or a similar or better journal) is compared to a paper in journal of algebra?
  Like 3 Journal of Algebra papers = one Advances of Math paper and 
  6 Journal of Algebra papers = 1 Inventiones paper?

Comment: There are some typos and capital letter missing, so it's hard to follow the question properly

Comment: I think it is a legitimate question. Actually, one of the most on topic and legitimate questions an academic can ask.

Comment: Probably not even a partial answer to your first question: The [Australian Mathematical Society ranks](https://www.austms.org.au/Rankings/AustMS_final_ranked.html) the Journal of Algebra among the best journals.

Comment: @Christian, actually it is a good answer. It shows the premise of the question might be false, which is helpful to the OP. This also shows why it is a completely legitimate question: if academic societies hold rankings, why should this forum shy away from such rankings?

Comment: @Christian Unfortunately, that list is outdated by now. Also, it seems that Journal of Algebra has been in a bit of decline in the mean time. Finally, while it it ranked the highest there, it is still not (nor was it at the time the list was made) anywhere near the level of journals like Advances (or even less Inventiones).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I completely agree. In addition, I think that even if the ranking was completely up to date it could not provide a complete answer to the question since I does not reflect how much a certain community values articles in "general" journals.

Comment: One thing which seems not to have been mentioned: J of Alg is a _specialist journal_, while Math Zeit, JLMS and IMRN are all _general_ journals. This may or may not be a factor which affects likelihood of getting your papers accepted in these other journals.

Comment: A separate point: it is difficult to answer questions like "will this course of action be detrimental to my career" because this depends on the academic and professional culture in which you work. For instance, the issues about "which journals do I aim for?" seem to be different in Canada from the UK (to name the two systems I have experience of) and if you work in Australia / NZ then your university may set much greater store by the AustMS journal ranking than, say, if you worked in Switzerland

Comment: I tried rephrasing the question so it is no longer a shopping question.  Apologies to the OP if I have misrepresented anything.

Comment: @YemonChoi, right. That's why we should ask the OP to clarify which system and country they work in.

Comment: I voted to re-open. So, now it's re-opened. However, I'd like to say something about the last secondary question: it's a "shopping question" - we don't do comparisons. Please remove it at your convenience.

Comment: @YemonChoi _AustMS journal ranking_ <-- which have been deprecated for over half a decade. Not to mention the existence of newer top-tier journals with no rankings.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I have a coauthor in NZ whose university seem to care about these things, and therefore by transitivity he has to care about these. Not all of us have free-range luxury. (Also look up REF)

Comment: @Yemon I don't doubt there are places (and not just in Australasia) that treat the AustMS rankings as gospel. I will just continue to point out that the body that requested the rankings (the Australian Research Council) now disavows their continued use.

Comment: Advances was very good. However, it publishes 500 papers a year. Still, many mathematicians publishes very good papers in Advances, but there are already quite a few `not good` papers in Advances now. If it keeps publishing 500 a year, it will be worse.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think that "generalist vs specialist" is the right question to ask.  Rather, I think that you should think of journals as being in various tiers of quality.  Notice that I'll express some opinions on specific journals below, and other mathematicians might disagree with them.  It is worthwhile to talk to a good number of senior people to help get a sense as to what tier various journals occupy.  I don't think that impact factors are what really matters here, but rather the subjective opinions of whoever will be evaluating your cv (at least in the US, this is mostly other mathematicians).

Some subject-specific journals are really excellent (e.g. Geometry and Topology, Algebra and Number Theory, Journal of Algebraic Geometry), some are decent but not excellent (I think that the Journal of Algebra fits this bill), others are pretty terrible (I won't make a list here so as to avoid starting a debate).

It is true that the very best generalist journals (Annals, Inventiones, JAMS, Acta, Publications IHES, Duke, JEMS) occupy a higher tier than even the best subject-specific journals.  However, it's not clear to me that the excellent but not top generalist journals (eg Math Zeitschrift) are clearly better than the best subject-specific journals.

You should try very hard to have your papers in the best journals that you can get to accept them.  Editors at strong journals are used to getting papers that are not directly related to their research, so you shouldn't stress out about sending your papers to them.

As to your final question (about how many papers in one tier are needed to get the equivalent quality of one paper in a higher tier), the correct answer is probably "infinity".  When I evaluate someone's cv, I am trying to figure out how good their best work is.  One paper in the Annals trumps any number of papers in lesser journals.

Comment: Could you expand upon why you are trying to figure out the quality of someone's best work (as opposed to median or most common work)? Although that's not strictly speaking necessary to answer the question, I think it would be of great interest to graduate students and non-tenure faculty reading this post. I for one was quite surprised to read that.

Comment: I'll let Andy speak for himself, but this is a very common attitude among mathematics faculty especially (compared to other fields).

Comment: Echoing @TomChurch, and echoing Andy Putman, I, too, want to see the _best_ that a candidate can do, not their average. I think a reason for this is that "good/average" stuff eventually becomes trite or banal, as ambient technique improves, while the really unusual stuff involves truly new ideas, and is more creative and "generative" for other peoples' work.

Comment: @StellaBiderman: Any well-trained mathematician can crank out an arbitrary number of routine, mediocre papers.  It's much harder to do something genuinely new and profound, and these are the papers that really matter in the long run.  When I'm evaluating someone (for a job, grant, etc.), my goal is to figure out who really has the potential to make that kind of serious contribution.

Comment: (I should say that I'm probably one of those people who write too many papers, but I admire people who write fewer but more substantial papers)

Comment: _Notice that I'll express some opinions on specific journals below, and other mathematicians might disagree with them._ - A minor addendum: the reputation of journals (especially general ones) can vary quite a bit from field to field, so even rough "consensus rankings" will vary between fields.  (Yet another reason hard journal rankings are impossible, and many people think in terms of rough tiers, like Andy.)

Comment: _One paper in the Annals trumps any number of papers in lesser journals._ <-- what about Fields medal-level papers published only on the arXiv? :-P

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Of course, this only applies to candidates whose research I do not personally understand; for people in my field, I have my own opinions, which do not always completely line up with the journals where papers appear.  And even there, if I am trying to convince other people to support my favorite candidate, I will use phrases like "This paper could have appeared in the Annals."  Conversely, I always exhibit skepticism when someone says that about a paper that appeared in a non-top journal, so such a claim needs to be backed up with serious evidence.

Comment: If someone is skeptical toward your claim of an Annals-worthy paper, how do you justify your claim? Forgive my skepticism, but you seem to be holding a double standard, willing to let the journal be the nigh-definitive measure of quality for the vast majority of papers (I hope it is uncontroversial that no one at this point understands a majority of mathematical papers) and asking for strong evidence, but unless you convince me you have what amounts to a crystal ball (perhaps you have access to Annals editors and can ask their private opinion on a paper you suspect they may have accepted...)

Comment: It seems you are asking others to accept your say-so on papers. Clearly there might be cases where it's obvious (proving a well-known big conjecture in any case receives publicity after all) but how do you decide on borderline cases? Moreover, how do you know that a paper you think of highly hasn't already been rejected by the Annals? Maybe the referees and editors there sometimes have to make a hard call and decide against what people might have thought "should" happen. Just food for thought for others, my position in "the game" will

Comment: not cause a blip on your radar I am sure (and to be transparent, I haven't had a paper rejected from the Annals, I have no grudge there). Substitute any other highly regarded journal for the Annals in my above comment if you prefer.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: The Annals (which I am just using as an example; there are other journals at that level) makes mistakes, so I am using that phrase to indicate that *in my opinion* the paper in question is important enough to justify its publication in a top-level journal.  If one makes such a claim to other people, one had better be prepared to back it up by mathematical arguments: a discussion of the history of the problem, how it connects to other areas, why it is difficult and important, etc.  The same kinds of things you include when you referee papers for top-level journals.

Comment: I certainly don't make claims that I am unwilling to defend and explain.  I should say that I also know of examples in the other direction (where a top-level journal accepted a paper they shouldn't have), and I have made that case before as well.  It's how these kinds of committees work.  A bunch of people go in a room with evidence marshaled in support of their point of view and argue it out until they reach consensus.

Comment: @Andy thanks for responding. The system is noisy and prone to error all round, methinks.

Comment: I agree on the whole that quality is far more important than quantity, but I think Andy is overstating it a bit here.  First because there's a lot of luck (especially early in career) in terms of whether a great idea ends up turning into something Annals level or "merely" Advances/G&T level, and second because energy matters (especially in a colleague).  A good rate of excellent papers in my mind can be more important than one truly exceptional one.

Answer (score 0):

As a senior PhD candidate, my opinion is as follows:

> Is it considered to be much better to have a publication in such a general journal than in a specialized journal like Journal of Algebra? I made the experience that sending my papers to Journal of Algebra, one gets a much quicker publication and the editors are closer to my field. So from my side I would just send all my papers to Journal of Algebra or another specialised journal, but I assume that this will look weird in my CV. Does it harm me if I do this even when some of my papers could go into a slightly better journal like Mathematische Zeitschrift? I feel uncomfortable sending my papers to editors that are far away from my field of research.

This question has multiple aspects to be considered:

1. **Type of study**: As in, where does it fall between being a theoretical paper to applied sciences. Theoretical papers are already very hard to publish and they are often too specific. In this case I do not think it is particularly bad to submit to the same journal. On the other hand, application studies can go both ways: too specific or too generic. If it is too specific, it can be better to submit to a journal which is sector specific. (i.e. You do not submit a marine application to civil engineering journal.) If it is too generic, by which I mean you do not improve a theory or propose a new method, but instead illustrate a method's performance, you should submit to a journal with a higher impact factor.

   2. **Quality over Quantity**: If you are required to publish a specific amount of papers annually for reasons, it should not matter in which journal you publish as long as it meets the standards. Since they are taking quantity over quality, then I do not think anyone would give a second glance to the papers. On the other hand, when quality weighs heavier, you should try to leave your comfort zone and submit to different journals too. Everybody has something to improve your work even if you get rejected. Even more considering that you may have submitted a paper to a *better* journal and was rejected, you can then use that information to improve your study and submit again.
   3. **More on comfort zones**: I think that if you are bothered by this question and you have other alternatives, then you are not comfortable being in your *comfort zone*. Take your chances with other journals as well. At worst you receive a rejection. If you believe in your study, why not publish it in a journal with a high impact factor and prestige. (I have been trying to get a paper accepted for a journal for 4 years. I was rejected by 12 different journals so far, with reasons varying from *we are too good for you,* to *it's not you, it's me*. I have re-written the paper twice from scratch. With each rejection I improved something and now I am more eager to publish it because it has **really** improved. I am now waiting for an answer from the 13th journal.)

> How bad is it to have a very good paper (that might be suitable for the best general journals) published in a journal like Journal of Algebra?

If you think that you could do better than this, then *yes, it is bad to publish a very good paper in a mediocre journal*. Also refer to answers above.

> Can one give an approximate how much worth a paper in Advances of Math (or a similar or better journal) is compared to a paper in journal of algebra? Like 3 Journal of Algebra papers = one Advances of Math paper and 6 Journal of Algebra papers = 1 Inventiones paper?

I do not know if there is an exact formula about this. I would guess *impact factor* is what you are looking for. The higher the impact factor, the better the recognition you will get. Also check which index a journal is under.

Comment: _Impact factor_ is highly debatable. Of course, this depends on whether one interprets the "worth" of a paper as "how much will it help my career prospects", which in turn depends on "do I work in an academic system where people who affect my career prospects care about impact factor"

Comment: In the U.S., it does not appear that mathematicians care about so-called "impact factors", currently.

Comment: I am not a mathematician but in Turkey quantity is more important if you want tenure at state universities. Which in my opinion is very very sad.

Comment: As in my comment above, echoing Tom Church and Andy Putman, if the metric is "maximum" of quality of journals, which is approximately the case in current mathematics in the U.S., then _no_ number of lesser-quality journal publications is equivalent to a single highest-quality publication. In particular, from this viewpoint, "impact factor" is completely useless and misleading. E.g., 1,000 crappy papers, or 10,000, or 100,000, will not be "as good" as a single paper in The Annals of Math, for example.

Comment: ... and, for that matter, a huge number of crappy papers is a damning indictment of one's lack of good judgement, in many ways.

Comment: _where does it fall between being a theoretical paper to applied sciences_ <-- the OP explicitly said they work on mathematics of a theoretical nature. I guess you're trying to put a different perspective forward that might be more widely useful? Also, I respectfully say that maybe your background (not a mathematician, based in the Turkey) should be stated up front. Different fields and different countries have different standards.

Comment: @paulgarrett while at an abstract level I agree with your comment on "a huge number of crappy papers", I do think there is a danger on many online sites that discuss maths (MO, MSE, here, the SBS diaspora) of "let them eat brioche". _Other people in other systems face other pressures and (dis)incentives._

Comment: @DavidRoberts Ofcourse standards vary across the world, OP asked an area specific question but I do not think question is so. I do not think quality of a work depends on the subject. Science is science. Neverthless, thank you for your comment. I will write my next answers more thorough.

Comment: @YemonChoi, yes, certainly, it is all too easy to over-interpret any numerical comparison of papers in top-status journals to low-status journals. At the very least, I'd certainly want to reiterate that "intending to write top-status papers" is a silly thing, since one does what one can, and it is what it is. "Scoring status points" is perhaps necessary, but I'd claim as a _side-effect_ of an intellectually/scientifically more genuine activity that is _not_ literally "aiming to score status points". Doing profound work is not a matter of volition or ambition.